# What is the word for something that is frowned upon based on cultural atmosphere

Tags: single-word-requests

I think it starts with a “t”.

Sample sentence:

> It is considered ________ to discuss your paycheck.

Comment: Are you thinking of "taboo"?

Comment: Single word requests are supposed to have example sentences. I personally think your example should be close enough, but I've seen sticklers vote to close requests with similar statements, rather than something like `For example, 'Sharing your paycheck is _____.'` If they do vote to close it for lack of an example sentence, the one I just mentioned should work for you.

Comment: "Inappropriate" not good enough? Ends with "t", which makes you think it starts with "t".

Answer (score 5):

A word starting with "T" for "something that is frowned upon based on cultural atmosphere" would be:

> **[taboo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/taboo)**
>   NOUN
>
> 1. A social or religious custom prohibiting or restricting a particular practice or forbidding association with a particular person, place, or thing.
>
>    - *‘many taboos have developed around physical exposure’*
>    - *‘the use of violence must remain a taboo in our society’*
>    - [mass noun] *‘Freud applies his notion of taboo in three ways’*
>
> > 1.1 A practice that is prohibited or restricted by social or religious custom.
> >
> > > - *‘speaking about sex is a taboo in his country’*
>
> **Origin**
>   Late 18th century: from Tongan *tabu* ‘set apart, forbidden’; introduced into English by Captain Cook.
>
> [Source: Oxford Living Dictionaries]

---

EDIT

The question was edited since I posted the above answer, and now includes a sample sentence that suggests the solution would be an *adjective* rather than a noun (which the original wording of *"something"* had required):

> It is considered ________ to discuss your paycheck.

Strictly speaking it would be permissible to use a noun here (e.g. *heresy*, *mutiny* or a mass noun like *violence*), and indeed the above definition includes an example of *taboo* as a mass noun that could be used in the sample sentence. However, *taboo* is also an adjective and would perfectly suit the sample sentence in that sense.

Oxford Dictionaries provides the following definition (from the same linked page):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Prohibited or restricted by social custom.
>
>    - *‘sex was a taboo subject’*
>    - *‘Certain subjects are taboo, or too emotive to be examined with objectivity.’*